# How redirect from my_category.phtml to controller method in magento?

Tags: magento, php

I created my_category with some products in backend magento and I have controller with method products.

How can I redirect customer to http://bla-bla.com/controller/products from http://bla-bla.com/my_category.phtml?

Thanks.

Comment: try to use Magento Custom Url Rewrites (admin panel Catalog->URL Rewrites management).

Comment: You can remove the rewrite from DB and magento will display URL as it is